# how to append new key and value in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries

```
m = [ {'currency_id':1,'price':20},{'currency_id':2,'price':25},{'currency_id':1,'price':44}]
```

1 means USD and 2 means Bitcoin. So, i have to check currency id in every dictionary and if price is in USD then i have to convert usd to bitcoin and add a new key,value pair 'bitcoin_price':1.0  or if price is in bitcoin then i have to convert it to usd and append a new key,value pair 'usd_price':33. At last i want list like this

```
m = [ {'currency_id':1,'price':20,'bitcoin_price':1.0},{'currency_id':2,'price':25,'usd_price':33},{'currency_id':1,'price':44,'bitcoin_price':1.0}]
```

I have already tried something but seems like i'm lost.

```
m = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'d':1,'f':3,'t':6}]
for i,k in enumerate(m):
    for w in k:
        if k[w]==1:
            k['as']=5555

        else:
            k['l']=23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
new_m = []
bitcoin_usd_price = 5000

for obj in m:
        new_m.append(obj)
        if obj['currency_id'] == 2:
            new_m[-1]['usd_price'] = obj['price'] * bitcoin_usd_price
        else:
            new_m[-1]['bitcoin_price'] = obj['price'] / bitcoin_usd_price
m = new_m
```

Now just assign `bitcoin_usd_price` to an actual currency conversion ratio (cost of bitcoin in usd).

UPD: changing `m` list of the fly would be a neater solution:

```
bitcoin_usd_price = 5000

for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i]['currency_id'] == 2:
            m[i]['usd_price'] = m[i]['price'] * bitcoin_usd_price
        else:
            m[i]['bitcoin_price'] = m[i]['price'] / bitcoin_usd_price
```

Comment: Hi thanks for input, i replaced bitcoin_usd_price with a random integer 2 but it is giving me this error. 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/f.py", line 11, in <module>
    new_m['bitcoin_price'] = obj['price'] /2
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: It's just the last added object. As you can see, at the beginning of the loop I add object to new list and then change it. Of course, you can change object if m on the fly, I'll extend my answer now.

Comment: thanks for the update, i have upvoted and have accepted your answer. though its a off topic here may i ask which book or material should i follow so my python can be more strong?

Comment: @aryan, imo, the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) is a great place to start and learn, and it's comprehensive enough